# Library libcgsqlite3.dylib not loaded error FireDAC sqlite

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

I'm new to using Delphi to create a Mac Desktop app. Hello World, no problem. But when I try to use Sqlite via FireDAC, I get this error and unsure how it is resolved. Should this library file not be deployed when I build the app from my Windows machine?

dyld[2958]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcgsqlite3.dylib
....
(no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libcgsqlite3.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libcgsqlite3.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)

Comment: You need to add the SQLite drivers to the deployment. In Delphi: Project | Deployment, click the "Add featured files" button (4th from the left), scroll down to SQLite Engine and select OSX64 (and OSXARM64 if your app will target ARM Macs)

Comment: Thanks! You save me perhaps hours of time.